# Continuous functions such that $\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt=\frac{f(x)}{2}+1$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Find all continuous functions $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, such that $\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt=\frac{f(x)}{2}+1$

---

Differentiating I obtain $f(x)=\frac{f'(x)}{2}$, so $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=2$ and integrating $\ln(f(x))=2x$, so $f(x)=e^{2x}$, but this function doesn't satisfy the hypothese

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align*}
f(x)&=\dfrac{f'(x)}{2}\\
2f(x)&=f'(x)\\
f'(x)-2f(x)&=0\\
e^{-2x}f'(x)-2e^{-2x}f(x)&=0\\
(e^{-2x}f(x))'&=0\\
e^{-2x}f(x)&=C\\
f(x)&=Ce^{2x},
\end{align*}
substituting into the integral equation, we find $C=-2$.

Comment: You need to multiply by $e^{-2x}$ and the final answer would then $-2e^{2x}$.

Answer (score 2):

Differentiate to get
$$f(x)=\frac{f'(x)}{2}$$ 
so
$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=2$$
and integrating
$$\ln(f(x))=2x+C$$
so
$$f(x)=Ae^{2x}$$

Substitute it back to the original equation we have
$$\int_0^x Ae^{2t}dt=\frac{A}{2}e^{2x}+1$$
$$\frac{A}{2}e^{2x}-\frac{A}{2}=\frac{A}{2}e^{2x}+1$$
$$A=-2$$
So the function is

$$-2e^{2x}$$